# Atomically drain one mpsc before another

Tags: multithreading, rust, atomic

I have two `std::sync::mpsc` receivers in a thread, a priority receiver and a regular receiver. Is there any way to atomically ensure the priority queue is drained before using the regular queue? I make sure that there is a happens-before relationship on `Sender`s so priority operations are always sent first.

Here is my current solution, which I am almost certain is incorrect:

```
loop {
    for priority_op in priority_rx.try_iter() {
        match priority_op {
            ...
        }
    }
    
    // A priority op, and then a regular op could arrive here

    let op = rx.recv().unwrap();
    match op {
        ...
    }
}
```

If this is impossible, what would be an alternative architecture I could use (besides only having a single queue) to achieve this behavior?

Comment: The CPU can't atomically load from 2 locations at once, so the best you can do is check the high-priority queue one last time as late as possible before passing the point of no return in starting to work on a low-priority item.  If you really want to decrease latency at the cost of throughput, you could try to make the low-priority work abortable, so you can discard partial progress if another check of the priority queue sees an item after you've already started working on a regular item.  That means running more code to do these checks, of course, as well as discarded work, or even rollbacks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the priority channel after you receive something on the regular channel.

```rs
loop {
    for priority_op in priority_rx.try_iter() {
        use_priority(priority_op);
    }

    // A priority op, and then a regular op could arrive here

    let op = rx.recv().unwrap();
    let raced_priority = priority_rx.try_recv();

    if let Ok(raced) = raced_priority {
        // return op to queue
        tx.send(op);
        use_priority(raced);
    } else {
        // No race occurred
        use_op(op);
    }
}
```

This has the big drawback that you lose the regular channel's ordering. So instead, you could put the regular op into a local variable.

```rs
let mut regular = None;
loop {
    for priority_op in priority_rx.try_iter() {
        use_priority(priority_op);
    }

    // This op was received in the last loop
    if let Some(event) = regular.take() {
        use_op(event);
    }

    // A priority op, and then a regular op could arrive here

    let op = rx.recv().unwrap();
    let raced_priority = priority_rx.try_recv();
    if let Ok(raced) = raced_priority {
        // return op to queue
        regular = Some(op);
        use_priority(raced);
    } else {
        // No race occurred
        use_op(op);
    }
}
```

This can be better written if you shift the loop around.

```rs
loop {
    let op = rx.recv().unwrap();
    let raced_priority = priority_rx.try_recv();

    let regular = if let Ok(raced) = raced_priority {
        use_priority(raced);
        // return op to queue
        Some(op)
    } else {
        // No race occurred
        use_op(op);
        None
    };

    for priority_op in priority_rx.try_iter() {
        use_priority(priority_op);
    }

    // This op was received before draining priority_rx
    if let Some(event) = regular {
        use_op(event);
    }
}
```

In order to keep up responsiveness on the priority queue, you may want to remove `recv` and instead use `recv_timeout` or `try_recv`, and you'd probably want to do that on the priority queue instead.

```rs
loop {
    let regular = match rx.try_recv() {
        Ok(op) => {
            let raced_priority = priority_rx.try_recv();

            if let Ok(raced) = raced_priority {
                // return op to queue
                use_priority(raced);
                Some(op)
            } else {
                // No race occurred
                use_op(op);
                None
            }
        }
        Err(TryRecvError::Empty) => None,
        Err(_) => panic!("Disconnected"),
    };

    if let Ok(priority_op) = priority_rx.recv_timeout(some_duration) {
        use_priority(priority_op);
        for priority_op in priority_rx.try_iter() {
            use_priority(priority_op);
        }
    }

    // This op was received before draining priority_rx
    if let Some(event) = regular {
        use_op(event);
    }
}
```

This means that if the regular channel is empty, priority channel will be used as soon as possible, and if the priority channel is empty, the regular channel may be delayed by up to `some_duration` (plus the loop overhead for both). If you want to be constantly checking the queue, you can use `try_recv` instead of `recv_timeout`, and include a [`spin_loop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hint/fn.spin_loop.html) hint.

After writing that I realized it can be compressed.

```rs
loop {
    let regular = rx.try_recv();

    if let Ok(priority_op) = priority_rx.recv_timeout(some_duration) {
        use_priority(priority_op);
        for priority_op in priority_rx.try_iter() {
            use_priority(priority_op);
        }
    }

    // This op was received before draining priority_rx
    if let Ok(event) = regular {
        use_op(event);
    }
}
```

And the version that spins.

```rs
loop {
    let regular = rx.try_recv();

    for priority_op in priority_rx.try_iter() {
        use_priority(priority_op);
    }

    // This op was received before draining priority_rx
    if let Ok(event) = regular {
        use_op(event);
    }

    spin_loop();
}
```

At this point it's transformed quite a bit from your original, but I think it should do what you're looking for. It also ignores the channels hanging up, so you should probably add that in.

There's probably a data structure better suited for this specific task, but I don't know of it, it's not in the standard library, and you may have to build it from scratch. Hopefully someone can post an answer if this does exist.

Comment: There's an extra `match` in `let regular = match rx.try_recv();` in your last two code samples.